# Why do we get FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths on LocalDB but not SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6, localdb

Why do we get foreign key constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths on LocalDB but not on SQL Server Express or SQL Azure?

We are running Entity Framework 6.20 and we have tried to set the values:

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.CategoryId, cascadeDelete: false)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Files", t => t.FileId, cascadeDelete: false)
```

In the migration but we still get the same exception, this does however work on none LocalDb.

It is a "many to many" table and a code-first database and I am running the migration programmatically.

Comment: You shouldn't change the migration code but the EF mapping configuration. AFAIK there is no difference between localdb and Azure when it comes to this foreign key restriction, so there seems to be a difference between the databases before the migration.

Comment: @GertArnold It is a empty database, When we use SQL Server Express 2016 or Azure the migration runs fine with cascadeDelete set to true, no error but when switching to LocalDB and first time migration we get this error. We also did not need to set cascadeDelete to false in the migration as we mentioned before. We just tested if it would work on LocalDB by setting it to false. We want to use LocalDB for Unit testing on Visual Studio Online.